# How to test web socket?

Tags: node.js, apache, sockets, http, websocket

I have a web server as in url below implemented web socket.

```
zmy02dev02v.ap.freescale.net:8181/widget
```

I recently heard about thor as below

```
https://github.com/observing/thor
```

I install it to test load on the web socket in the application running in mentioned web server.
Now, i have some confusion here, how I should put the link to test the web socket in thor.
I put the url as above and i get error
[image]

But when I try inspect in Chrome to see where the web socket connect it show like below and the url keep change dynamic each time refreshed.
[image]

When I put this url into the thor, and i get some respond like below
[image]

So i am totally confused here, which url I need to use to test load for web socket implemented. Appreciate any help explain me or guide through on this as I am beginner in web socket.

Comment: Use artillery.io for WebSocket test